# i am getting parshing error as " Line 4:7: Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";" "

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

// Here is my code

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

Class Student extends Component
{

    render()
    {
        return <h1>Why are you so sad</h1>;
    }
}
export default Student;
```

Comment: is your file named `.js` or `.jsx`?

Comment: It's `Class` or `class` in your code?

Comment: It's .js. But i got my answer since i used wrong syntax for class. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong syntax at `Class Student extends Component`. It should be `class Student extends Component`.

Comment: Sorry, for such a silly mistake. Thank you so much for answering it.

Comment: @Rupaksinghchauhan Please upvote and accept my answer if it's helpful. Thank you so much!